# A word for a person who tells you information, instead of letting you find it out by yourself

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For example: if someone told you that the laundry was dry, instead of just letting you find it out by yourself when you go and check it.

Another example: if someone knocked on your bedroom door to tell you that a package had arrived in the mail, instead of just leaving the package for you to find.

Third example: If someone tells you that there's milk in the fridge, instead of just letting you see it by yourself when you open it.

Is there a word for people like that?

Comment: I'm not sure that your examples are all comparable. I would want to know that a package had come for me, but I don't care about milk status.

Comment: How would you use the word (in a useful way) in a sentence?

Comment: If a package arrived for me I would prefer if my flatmate just left it somewhere where I would see it, instead of knocking on my door to let me know.

Comment: @jon That is beside the point, unless you consider the behaviour of those people for whom you want a name to be not quite proper and then the word you want has to have some negative connotations, be disapproving possibly;  that seems to be the case. You'd do well to make precise, if you can, what you reproach these people with.

Comment: Some might say they were kind and considerate.  Others might say they were interfering or intrusive.  Which do you wish to convey?

Comment: The intrusive one.

Comment: On ELU, LMGTFY-er.

Answer (score 0):

The comments request a negative word, so you could say that person is a **busybody**.
[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/busybody) has

> **busybody**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> A meddling or prying person.
> *others considered him an interfering busybody*

It describes a person who is always poking their nose into other people's business.

Answer (score -1):

With words it is easy to call the behaviour of a kind, thoughtful person  that of a [slavey](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=slavey) and vice versa.

So, as it is not clear what particular quirk or aspect of behaviour is to be retained,  here are several possibilities in a range from disapproving to approving; however, only one single word terms figures in the list; I doubt that very many single word terms should be available.

- slavey (derogatory meaning perhaps only in AmE)
- a thoughtful/kind person to the point of intrusiveness
- too thoughtful/kind a person
- a thoughtful/kind person
- a very thoughtful/kind person
- a helpful person

Comment: Urban Dictionary isn't a reliable reference for common usage. Anybody can put up any kind of thing, and "slavey" is at best only used in certain areas/cultures.

Comment: @StuartF I think you are right; as I do not depend entirely on Urban Dictionary, which served only my purpose of verifying the disapproving sense that I suspected  this word to have in American, I think that my claim is solid enough; however, I should add a precision (perhaps only AmE).